# Make API requests recursively without large number of processes running

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, kill, recursive

I have the following Script File 'bored.sh'. This file recursively calls itself.

```
curl "https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity" >>./bored.json
sleep 1s
bash ./bored.sh
```

I realized that this is a bad approach as it creates several instances and runs many processes that uses the system resources and ultimately crashes the system.

How do I terminate/kill all the previous instances of the scripts after they are executed (series of API call and store those response to file) sequentially but make sure this script runs indefinitely as only one or few child process and create less stress to my system?

**EDIT**
I need to get the data from the API and store it to a file 'bored.json' once in  every second.

Comment: This should probably be an infinite loop that keeps calling the same script. `while true; do ./bored.sh; done` and while you're at it, add a `sleep` in there too so it's not running all the time (unless that is your goal).

Comment: True. But how do i kill all the previous parent instances as these are using lot of my system resources. Here is a image of my Task Manager Processes! https://postimg.cc/5jHyJgGK

Comment: `killall` might be able to help you - `killall bored.sh`

Comment: Thanks. I think this kills all the processes. But I want the script to be running and only kill processes that has been completed(the parent and not the child). In the image above I've shown multiple instances of same script running and taking up resources in my device ultimately crashing my system. And I need to stop that from happening. I hope you understand!

Comment: You don't seem to understand that your processes never 'complete' as they recursively wait for the next iteration. It's an XY problem which arises from how you choose to run things. This script should only be running once, in a single process.

Comment: Gotcha! Is there something you'd recommend to accomplish this! Without creating such large number of processes. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and start from the beginning. Explain what your script is trying to achieve, and then we can give you a way to do that.

Comment: @Panki .  Thanks I seem to had little confusion with recursion and looping statement. Not now. Your first answer actually helped. `while` is running in a single process! I started out with wrong approach of file calling itself and created the mess there!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out, feel free to add your approach as an answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with the help of above the community comments. Instead of recursively calling the file itself as in the above code, I used looping statements to loop through my requirements. The code snippet is below.

```
while true; do
curl "https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity" >>./bored.json
sleep 1s
./bored.sh; done
```

I was able to get the expected performance with this one!